# angular.ui.popover not working with latest angular 1.3.3 and angular.ui.bootstrap 0.12.0

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created this pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEOKEK

It works if I use angular 1.2.X, but dies as soon as I go to 1.3. I need the ability to use popover-template.

```
      <p>
    <button popover-placement="bottom" popover-template="calendar.html" class="btn btn-default">Date Picker</button>
  </p>

  <script id="calendar.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-model="date">
      <datepicker show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="alert alert-success">{{ text }}</div>
  </script>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNzZX

Answer (score 2):

OK bottom line is - I spent HOURS trying to get angular.ui.popover to do this, but it just isn't engineered to allow custom html templates. I switched to nsPopover for angular, and I'm set. Much more flexible, better options. The tooltip / popover in angular.ui is only usable in the smallest use cases, ones so small I never see it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what angular-ui-bootstrap library you are using, but template support in the popover is not part of an official release, here is a [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1848) to the proposed pull request to add that feature.  The popover [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) does not list popover-template as a supported attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Popover templates are now a part of the latest release of Angular UI Bootstrap (0.13.0) and work with Angular 1.3.x

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover